# Generate a combination of URL endpoints

Tags: python, python-2.7, url, urlparse

I have a URL as follows:

```
http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/file.php
```

and I have an endpoint named `/potato`.

I would like to generate the following URLs from these:

```
http://example.com/foo/potato
http://example.com/foo/bar/potato
http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/potato
```

My attempts so far involved splitting at slashes, and it misses the case when the endpoint itself begins with a `/` etc.

What's the cleanest and Pythonic way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you are only just learning the basics, you should probably ignore Python 2, and spend your time on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
import re
s = 'http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/file.php'
*path, _ = re.split('(?<=\w)/(?=\w)', s)
results = [f'{"/".join(path[:2+i])}/potato' for i in range(len(path)-1)]
```

Output:

```
['http://example.com/foo/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/bar/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/potato']
```

---

Edit: Python2.7 Solution:

```
import re
s = 'http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/file.php'
path = re.split('(?<=\w)/(?=\w)', s)[:-1]
result = ['{}/potato'.format("/".join(path[:1+i])) for i in range(len(path))]
```

Output:

```
['http://example.com/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/bar/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/potato']
```

Another possibility to robustly and accurately parse the url is to use `urllib.parse`:

```
import urllib.parse
d = urllib.parse.urlsplit(s)
_, *path, _ = d.path.split('/')
result = [f'{d.scheme}://{d.netloc}/{"/".join(path[:i])}/potato' for i in range(1, len(path)+1)]
```

Output:

```
['http://example.com/foo/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/bar/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/potato']
```

In Python2.7 with `urlparse`:

```
import urlparse
d = urlparse.urlparse(s)
path = d.path.split('/')[1:-1]
result = ['{}://{}/{}/potato'.format(d.scheme, d.netloc, "/".join(path[:i]))  for i in range(len(path))]
```

Output:

```
['http://example.com/foo/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/bar/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/potato']
```

Edit 2: Timings:

Source for timings can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Ajax12345/fe48ae2abb1518c9ec79b0ff34b9c120)

[image]

From the graph, it appears that in majority of cases, `urlparse` is slower that `re`.

Edit 3: Generic solution:

```
import re
def generate_url_combos(s, endpoint):
   path = re.split('(?<=\w)/(?=\w)', re.sub('(?<=\w)/\w+\.\w+$|(?<=\w)/\w+\.\w+/+$', '', s).strip('/'))
   return ['{}/{}'.format("/".join(path[:1+i]), re.sub('^/|/+$', '', endpoint)) for i in range(len(path))]

tests = [('http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/file.php/', '/potato'), ('http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/file.php', '/potato'), ('http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/file.php', 'potato'), ('http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/file.php', 'potato/'), ('http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/file.php//', 'potato'), ('http://example.com/', 'potato'), ('http://example.com', 'potato'), ('http://example.com/', '/potato'), ('http://example.com', '/potato')]
for a, b in tests:
   print generate_url_combos(a, b)
```

Output:

```
['http://example.com/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/bar/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/potato']
['http://example.com/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/bar/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/potato']
['http://example.com/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/bar/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/potato']
['http://example.com/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/bar/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/potato']
['http://example.com/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/bar/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/potato']
['http://example.com/potato']
['http://example.com/potato']
['http://example.com/potato']
['http://example.com/potato']
```

---

Edit 4:

```
import urlparse, re
def generate_url_combos(s, endpoint):
   d = urlparse.urlparse(s)
   path = list(filter(None, d.path.split('/')))
   if not path:
     return '{}://{}/{}'.format(d.scheme, d.netloc, re.sub('^/+|/+$', '', endpoint))
   path = path[:-1] if re.findall('\.\w+$', path[-1]) else path
   return ['{}://{}/{}'.format(d.scheme, d.netloc, re.sub('^/+|/+$', '', endpoint) if not i else "/".join(path[:i])+'/'+re.sub('^/+|/+$', '', endpoint))  for i in range(len(path)+1)]

tests = [('http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/file.php/', '/potato'), ('http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/file.php', '/potato'), ('http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/file.php', 'potato'), ('http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/file.php', 'potato/'), ('http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/file.php//', 'potato'), ('http://example.com/', 'potato'), ('http://example.com', 'potato'), ('http://example.com/', '/potato'), ('http://example.com', '/potato')]
for a, b in tests:
   print generate_url_combos(a, b)
```

Output:

```
['http://example.com/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/bar/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/potato']
['http://example.com/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/bar/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/potato']
['http://example.com/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/bar/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/potato']
['http://example.com/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/bar/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/potato']
['http://example.com/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/bar/potato', 'http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/potato']
['http://example.com/potato']
['http://example.com/potato']
['http://example.com/potato']
['http://example.com/potato']
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the compactness of this solution, but is regex really required here? I can see that it's using lookarounds - if I'm going to use it millions of times, would it not be slower than say a solution that does not use regex? Interested in your thoughts.

Comment: Sadly, I'm using Python 2.7 - `*path` and the `f` format string won't work I believe. How would you convert that?

Comment: @JosephJohn Please see my recent edit, as I added solutions in Python2.7. Instead of regex, you can use `urllib` (Python 3) or `urlparse` (Python 2) to parse the urls. I will add speed tests momentarily.

Comment: @JosephJohn I also added timings. I think you will be interested by results.

Comment: Very interesting, indeed. Thanks for all the efforts. I would also like to have `http://example.com/potato` in my output. How would I modify this?

Comment: @JosephJohn  Please see my recent edit under the "Python2.7 Solution" solution.

Comment: This is much better. I'm trying to get the last 4 testcases working - https://eval.in/private/5ebc4a2e049ada - I believe this is something to do with the regex looking for a succeeding `/` and not finding it. Any idea how it can be changed to obtain the correct results?

Comment: There are two issues with this approach though :( First, the extension does not have to be `.php` all the time. Second, the 4th line has `/` appended to the end of the URL, which I'd like to avoid.